# Autohotkey KeyWait, how to use OR (||)

Tags: autohotkey

macro looks working without "OR MButton". how can I use both?

```
Loop
{
    KeyWait, RButton OR MButton
    KeyWait, RButton OR MButton, D
    CoordMode, Pixel, Window
    PixelSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 258, 762, 258, 762, 0x000402, 0, Fast RGB
    If ErrorLevel
        Break
    If ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        Send, {2}
        Sleep, 200
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the PixelSearch to be executed by, after or while pressing one of the buttons?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation] you can't as the only expected parameter is one key. You would likely need an independent loop to check for general key presses and check whenever it's the one you want to react to.

Comment: if press RButton, send 2.  
if press MButton, send 2.
That I want to do.
PixelSearch is control for {2} is free or not.
What kind a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't actually need a loop(??).

Do you just want to trigger on `RButton` or `MButton`, and execute something once per click?

```
~RButton::MyFunction()  ; Remove ~ to make these calls block the clicks from passing through
~MButton::MyFunction()  ; otherwise, leave in place to block clicks and send "2" instead

MyFunction() {
    PixelSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 258, 762, 258, 762, 0x000402, 0, Fast RGB
    If ErrorLevel
        Return

    Send, 2         ; Else if ErrorLevel was = 0, send "2"... shouldn't need brackets unless sending a special key
    ;Sleep, 200     ; Sleep only needed if executing lots of sends in a row or similar
}
```

I prefer to use functions (above) so the code is more modular.

You can do the same thing without them using typical sequential execution of hotkeys (below):

```
~RButton::  ; These will execute sequential code below...
~MButton::

    PixelSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 258, 762, 258, 762, 0x000402, 0, Fast RGB
    If ErrorLevel
        Return

    Send, 2         ; Else if ErrorLevel was = 0, send "2"... shouldn't need brackets unless sending a special key
    ;Sleep, 200     ; Sleep only needed if executing lots of sends in a row or similar

Return
```

If you wanted to send "2" repeatedly while `MButton` or `RButton` was down you could use a loop (something like your original code).  This would execute as long as one or the other button was clicked and held down:

```
~RButton::MyFunction()  ; Remove ~ to make these calls block the clicks from passing through
~MButton::MyFunction()  ; otherwise, leave in place to block clicks and send "2" instead

MyFunction() {
    ; Check to see if button is still down each loop iteration...
    While GetKeyState("P", "RButton") || GetKeyState("P", "MButton") {
        PixelSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 258, 762, 258, 762, 0x000402, 0, Fast RGB
        If ErrorLevel {
            Sleep 10
            Continue
        }

        Send, 2         ; Else if ErrorLevel was = 0, send "2"... shouldn't need brackets unless sending a special key
        Sleep, 200      ; Sleep only needed if executing lots of sends in a row or similar

    } 
}
```

Comment: wuw man you know what you doing